# What parts of speech are the words used in comparative clauses?

Tags: parts-of-speech, comparative-constructions

I would be grateful if someone could answer me what parts of speech the following words are labeled:  "more" in each of A1-A5; "than" in all of A1-A5; the first and second "as" in B1-B5; and "many/much" in B4 and B5.

(A) Inequalities:

- (A1) X is **more** stupid **than** Y.
- (A2) X does things **more** stupidly than Y.
- (A3) X does **more** things than Y.
- (A4) X does **more** (of the things) than Y.
- (A5) X is done **more** than Y.

(B) Equalities:

- (B1) X is **as** stupid **as** Y.
- (B2) X does things **as** stupidly as Y.
- (B3) X does **as** **many** things as Y.
- (B4) X does **as** **many** (of the things) as Y.
- (B5) X is done **as** **much** as Y.

I accept that there may be differences of opinion on how these words are labeled.  I would be more grateful if the answer was supported by a reference.  I have no desire to argue about what difference it makes to label parts of speech as such.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? You could start with [than](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/than).

Comment: Go luck up comparative forms with as ...as and more ...than.

Answer (score 0):

more x than is a comparative.
as many/much than y is also a comparative.

There are comparative adjectives (more things than) and adverbs (done more than or as much as).
as..as are for things that are equal.

The first is when one thing is **more than** another.
The other is when **two things are the same or are not the same as each other.**

Answer (score 0):

- "More" in A1, A2 and A5 are adverbs.
- "More" in A3 and A4 are, I believe, determiner and pronoun, respectively (although [POS tagging online](https://parts-of-speech.info/) tags them as adverbs).
- "Than" in A1-A5 are prepositions.
- The first "as" in A1-A5 are adverbs; the second "as" in A1-A5 are either prepositions (or possibly subordinating conjunctions).
- "Many" in B3 and B4 and "much" in B5 are, I believe, determiner and pronoun, respectively (although POS tagging online tags them as adjectives).